# R is there a way to dynamically update a function as you are building it

Tags: r, rstudio

I am very new to R and I am using RStudio. I am building a new "user-defined" function, which entails a huge amount of trial and error. Every time I make the slightest change to the function I need select the entire function and do `crtl+Enter` in order to "commit" the function to the workspace.

I am hoping there is a better way of doing it, perhaps in a separate window that automatically "commits" when I save.

I am coming from Matlab and am used to just saving the function after which it is already "committed".

Comment: Why is this problematic? If you function is very long, you might consider splitting it in smaller parts...

Comment: It is more annoying/time-consuming than anything else, having to scroll around and drag+selecting code with the mouse every single time you change something... As I said, I am used to Matlab which is just a bit simpler in this regard. As for you suggestion, I suppose it would aid in reducing the number of lines that need to be re-commited. Thanks, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+P` re-runs previously executed region, so you won't have to highlight your function again. so this will work unless you have executed something else in the interim.

Comment: Just to clarify why this is a good solution for me: This suggestion actually incorporates your latest code changes whereas "up arrow+enter" does not. Come to think of it, if you add more lines I wonder how crtl+shift+p knows this?? Care to explain @stas_g?

Comment: @gmarais i've just checked this and ctr+shift+p works even if you move the chunk of code around or insert new lines, so RStudio editor must be tracing previously executed lines. i don't really have a better explanation!

Comment: Well I will use it at my own risk, but it is a huge improvement on click+dragging with the mouse ad infinitum. I really despise working with a mouse and not shortcuts! Rant over, thanks very much again @stas g

Comment: @gmarais glad it's helpful:) if you could accept my answer as well that would be cool

Comment: Oh sorry, I clicked the up arrow thinking that "accepts" it but I believe the check mark does this. Seems I have a few questions I need to revisit and accept now.... thanks again.

Comment: Note that I got used personnaly to `Ctrl+Alt+F` to source solely current function definition. There are many shortcuts available for RStudio - every R user should pick his favorites - have a look at: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to run some part of your code in RStudio you simply have to use `Ctrl+Enter`. If the code were run every time you saved it, it could have *very* bad effects. Imagine that you have a huge script that runs for a long time and uses much computer resources - this would lead you to killing R to stop the script every time you saved it!

What you could do is to save script in external file and than call it from your main script using `source("some_directory/myscript.R")`.